# Magnific Popup - Index error

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I can't get my Magnific Popup working with index option. My goal is to make the gallery open on index of clicked image. In my HTML I have this for each image:

```
<div class="open_gallery_index" data-id=5><img ... ></div>
```

then my JS looks like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.open_gallery_index').click(function(){
    var i = Number($(this).data("id"));
    $.magnificPopup.open({
      items: g_items,
      gallery: {
        enabled: true
      },
      type: 'image'
    },i);
  });
})
```

But when clicking the image I get an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parsed' of undefined

Though if I set the variable i manually to let's say 5, everything works fine, so the problem must be in this

```
var i = Number($(this).data("id"));
```

but I have tried everything with no success, thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your 5 in quotes, like this?
<div class="open_gallery_index" data-id="5">

Comment: $(this).data("id") coming null

Comment: have you tried `parseInt()` instead of `Number()`

Comment: I have tried parseInt() and the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Update your `data-id` attribute like this.

```
<div class="open_gallery_index" data-id="5"><img ... ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `$.magnificPopup.open` requires an `src` property. Not really sure what `g_items` is in your code, but try something like this:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {
    src: '.open_gallery_index',
    type: 'image'
  }
  gallery: {
    enabled: true
  },
},i);
```

Comment: `g_items` is object with `src` & `time` array, that should be fine

Answer (score 0):

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
  items: g_items,
  gallery: {
    enabled: true
  },
  type: 'image'
},i);
i--;
i++;
```

it worked with me this way and I don't know why